# Checking and Removing NoneTypes for Jaro String Similarity

Tags: python, jaro-winkler

I'm trying to discern the string similarity between two strings (using Jaro). Each string resides in a separate column in my dataframe.

```py
String 1 = df['name_one'] 

String 2 = df['name_two']
```

When I try to run my string similarity logic:

```py
from pyjarowinkler import distance
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda d: distance.get_jaro_distance(str(d['name_one']),str(d['name_two']),winkler=True,scaling=0.1), axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

```
 **error: JaroDistanceException: Cannot calculate distance from NoneType (str, str)**
```

Great, so there is a nonetype in the columns, so the first thing I do is check for this:

```py
maskone = df['name_one'] == None
df[maskone]

masktwo = df['name_two'] == None
df[masktwo]
```

This yields in no None types found.... I'm scratching my head here at this point, but proceed to clean the two columns any ways.

```
df['name_one'] = df['name_one'].fillna('').astype(str)
df['name_two'] = df['name_two'].fillna('').astype(str)
```

And yet, I'm still getting:

```
error: JaroDistanceException: Cannot calculate distance from NoneType (str, str)
```

Am I removing NoneTypes correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The issue isn't exactly that you are only experiencing `NoneTypes` but **empty strings** which can also throw this exception as you can see in the [implementation](https://github.com/nap/jaro-winkler-distance/blob/master/pyjarowinkler/distance.py#L27) of `distance.get_jaro_distance`

```
if not first or not second:
    raise JaroDistanceException("Cannot calculate distance from NoneType ({0}, {1})".format(
        first.__class__.__name__,
        second.__class__.__name__))
```

#### Option 1

Trying replacing your none types and/or empty strings with 'NA' or filtering them from your dataset.

#### Option 2

Use a flag value/distance for rows that may raise this exception . In the example below, I will utilize `999`

```
from pyjarowinkler import distance

df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda d: 999 if not str(d['name_one']) or not str(d['name_two']) else distance.get_jaro_distance(str(d['name_one']),str(d['name_two']),winkler=True,scaling=0.1), axis=1)
```